# Query to fill in NULL values from form updates

Tags: excel, ms-access, null

Working in MS Access 2010 and expecting to receive 1,000s of changes in Excel format that I need to import into a personnel database.  I've been tasked with "automating" the update process but could really use some help.

The primary table has 12 fields that could each change for each change form submitted.  We have designed a macro to upload the Excel files but some of the fields on the change form will be blank, resulting in incomplete employee records (e.g. original employee record has all 12 records filled in, but change record only has 1).

Is it possible to write a query or macro to fill in the most recent employee record's empty or NULL values with the non-NULL values from the previous entries?

Comment: Yes. (But to be able to do that, you will need to store the last update time in a separate field, as "row numbers" don't exist in databases.)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to retain the value in the 'primary' table if the value in the 'change' table is null. In that case the following should work
`UPDATE <primaryTable> INNER JOIN <changeTable> ON <primaryTable>.<keyField> = <changeTable>.<keyField> SET <primaryTable>.<Field1> = nz(<changeTable>.<Field1>,<primaryTable>.<Field1>), <repeat for each field to update>`
Just be sure you are dealing with nulls and not empty strings, which is common in Excel imports. In that case you need to either change the empty strings to nulls or use an IIF statement instead of the nz function.